# PHP echo only if another PHP reference exists?

Tags: php, html, echo

Not sure if this is possible but what I am wanting to do is echo a html text link only if the page contains certain php code, in particular just the opening reference of 'myApi'. So if the page contains the following code:

```
<?php myAPI(variables); ?>
```

Then I would like to include this somewhere else on the page

```
<?php echo '<a href="http://www.website.com/">Click Here</a>'; ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: `<?php myAPI(variables); ?>` isn't valid PHP. Is that supposed to represent a function call? A constant? A variable?

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want to pre-process the page, but this is ill-advised. I'd definitely stick with @Steve's answer, there's almost never a good reason to to pre-process a server-side language.

Comment: @Francois Deschenes, I suppose referring to variables as an oddly declared value would be more specific. Nothing grammatically incorrect with myAPI, it just happens to be a terribly non-specific function name, which I suspect the OP realizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an `if` somewhere, and use `isset` to test if your API has set a specific variable or not.

```
if(isset($apiVariable)) {
  echo "link content...";
}
```

(The variable should be specific to your API, obviously.)

*Update*

I said "somewhere", but it's probably best to do the test logic it in a separate place than where you output the HTML.  In that case, you'd need a flag for when you're ready to spit out the HTML:

```
isset($apiVariable) ? $apiFlag = true : $apiFlag = false;
// continue other PHP operations...


//...now your logic is finished, output HTML.
if($apiFlag) { echo "<a>Link</a>"; }
```

That way, when you re-visit the page later for revision or update, your logic not all mixed up with your display.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if (isset($variable)): ?>

<a href="http://www.website.com/">Click Here</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The function `isset()` check if the variable is set and returns a boolean. so you can use it to check if a variable exist.